# Number the nearest to the average C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, numbers, average

does anybody knows what is wrong with 'else' gap and the script inside to show which number is the nearest to the average? I tried to fix it, however there was no better result. (It indicates the number, but wrongly)

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <math.h>

 using namespace std;

float average (float *a, int lib)
{
    float suma=0;
    for (int i=0;i<lib;i++)
    {
        suma+=*a;
        a++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return suma/lib;
 }


  int ile;

 int main()
 {     
     float *number;
     cout << "quantity of numbers: ";
     cin>> ile; 
     cout<<endl;

     number=new float [ile];
     for (int i=0; i<ile; i++)
     {

        cout<<"Give number: ";
        cin>>number[i];
     }

     double b=number[0];

    if (ile==2) {
        cout<<"liczby "<<number[0]<<" oraz "<<number[1]<<" sa w tej samej     odleglosci liczbowej od sredniej!";
    }
    if (ile==1) {
        cout<<"liczba "<<number[0]<<" jest w tej najbliższej odleglosci liczbowej od sredniej!";
    }
```

And here we go (upper there already is double b=number[0];)

```
      else {

     double  a=average(number,ile);
```

**That is supposed to show the number the nearest to the average**

```
          for (int i=0;i<ile;i++)
          {
              if ((fabs(a-b))<=(fabs(a-number[i]))) {
                  b=b;
              }
              else if ((fabs(a-b))>(fabs(a-number[i]))) {
                  b=liczba[i];
              }
              i++;
           }
    }
    cout<<b;
    delete [] number;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Tidying up the indentation would really help you (and us) to see the structure of the code. In the last section, you don't need to repeat the condition in the `else` clause, because it's already the opposite of the first condition. The first clause isn't needed at all, because when it's true you just do the no-op `b=b;`. But I think the main issue is that you increment `i` in the body of the loop, when it's already being incremented by the third clause in the `for (,,)` statement.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have just started my adventure with programming, nevertheless I am gonna take your advices to heart.

Comment: And thanks for the corrections, it worked instantaneously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is that you increment the i two times 
first int the for lop itself
and the second time after the if else statment
you for loop need to look like that:

```
for (int i=0;i<ile;i++)
{
    if ((fabs(a-b))<=(fabs(a-number[i]))) {
        b=b;
    }
    else if ((fabs(a-b))>(fabs(a-number[i]))) {
        b=liczba[i];
    }
    //i++; <-- delete this one
 }
```